# Remove img tags from xml with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

It's my first time using Python and BeautifulSoup. The thing is I'm doing a migration of all articles within a blog from one website to another, and to perform this, I'm extracting certain information from a xml file; the last part of my code tells to extract only the text between the position 0 and 164 from the  meta tag, so this way it can appear on google SERP as they want to appear.

The problem here is some articles from the blog has img tags on the first lines inside the  tag and I want to remove them, including the src attributes so the code can grab just the text after those img tags.

I tried to solve it in many ways but I did not succeed.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv
import sys
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

base_url = ("http://pimacleanpro.com/blog?rss=true")
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(base_url).read(),"xml")

titles = soup("title")
slugs = soup("link")
bodies = soup("description")

with open("blog-data.csv", "w") as f:
    fieldnames = ("title", "content", "slug", "seo_title", "seo_description","site_id", "page_path", "category")
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    output.writerow(fieldnames)

    for i in xrange(len(titles)):
        output.writerow([titles[i].encode_contents(),bodies[i].encode_contents(formatter=None),slugs[i].get_text(),titles[i].encode_contents(),bodies[i].encode_contents(formatter=None)[4:164]])

print "Done writing file"
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but I did not know how to fit it into the syntax. This is my first code that I write in python and I do not know how to solve it completely.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what it is you need to do? You want to remove any and all `<img>` tags and their contents within the `<description>`? Also it looks like you're using Python 2. If you want only Python 2 solutions you should tag Python 2.

Comment: Thank you @MihaiChelaru, I just tagged Python 2. As you can see inside http://pimacleanpro.com/blog?rss=true, there are 16 <description> tags, some of them has an <img>  tag just after it, I need to omits/remove the img tag so the line of code **bodies[i].encode_contents(formatter=None)[4:164]**  takes only the text  from the position 4 to 164 after that first img tag. As an example, you can review the third <description> tag, it has an img tag just after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Python 2.7 example that I think does what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

base_url = ("http://pimacleanpro.com/blog?rss=true")

# Unescape to allow BS to parse the <img> tags
soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(urlopen(base_url).read()))

titles = soup("title")
slugs = soup("link")
bodies = soup("description")

print bodies[2].encode_contents(formatter=None)[4:164]

# Remove all 'img' tags in all the 'description' tags in bodies
for body in bodies:
  for img in body("img"):
    img.decompose()

print bodies[2].encode_contents(formatter=None)[4:164]

# Proceed to writing to CSV, etc.
```

The first print statement outputs the following:

```
<img src='"http://ekblog.s3.amazonaws.com/contentp/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/03082910/decoration-design-detail-691710-300x221.jpg"'><br>
<em>Whether you are up
```

While the second one after removing the `<img>` tags is as follows:

```
<em>Whether you are upgrading just one room or giving your home a complete renovation, it’s likely that your first thought is to choose carpet for all of
```

Of course you could just remove all image tags in the soup object before creating `titles`, `slugs`, or `bodies` if they're not of interest to you:

```
for tag in soup("img"):
    tag.decompose()
```